# Insert Line with SED Before Each Multiline Range

Tags: windows, sed, gnu-sed

How can I insert a line before each multiline range block and indent the blocks in gnu sed on windows? The files contain many code blocks of various length starting and ending with ```. Answers to many similar questions using a single line pattern don't use ranges. There are two similar questions: [Insert line below text range with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755054/insert-line-below-text-range-with-sed) and [sed: Appending after a block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54385258/sed-appending-after-a-block/54388355#54388355).

This code indents all code blocks as required:

```` sed '/```/,/```$/ s/\(.*\)/    \1/' test.md ````

I don't understand how to insert the `===` line before each code block but I understand grouping with `{}` is required to process the block after inserting the line. The questions above seem more complex requiring a buffer but this file should be able to be processed sequentially without a buffer.

I expect something like this attempt should work with the newline detail before the group:

```` sed '/```/,/```$/ {s/\(.*\)/    \1/}' test.md ````

**test.md**

````
a
b
```
c
d
e
```
f
g
````

**Required**

````
a
b
===
    ```
    c
    d
    e
    ```
f
g
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

````
$ cat file
1
```
2
```
3
```
4
```
5
$ sed '/^```$/{ s/^/===\n    /; :a; n; s/^/    /; /^    ```$/b; ba; }' file
1
===
    ```
    2
    ```
3
===
    ```
    4
    ```
5
````

<sup>(The cool [sedsed](https://github.com/aureliojargas/sedsed) can show how it works in details.)</sup>

---

With awk:

````
$ awk '/^```/ { if (!f) { print "===" } f++ } f { print "    " $0 } f==2 { f=0; next } !f' file
1
===
    ```
    2
    ```
3
===
    ```
    4
    ```
5
````

Comment: Nice. Comments 1) GNU sed on Windows requires ^^(ie escaped) 2) if code language given after ``` remove first $. Can you describe new `sed` commands?

Comment: "new" sed command? "the" sed command? please use the sed debugger [sedsed](https://github.com/aureliojargas/sedsed).